Additive Utility Representation
I am going over an old problem set exercise and cannot figure out how certain conclusions follow in the proof my professor has given. There are several other questions on this topic on here (e.g., this question and this other question), but my question is about parsing the particular proof my professor has presented.
Suppose I have a rational (i.e. complete and transitive) preference relation $(\succeq)$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Consider the following axioms.

$\textbf{MON}$: $a\geq b$ (pointwise) implies $a\succeq b$. Also, if $a\neq b$ and $a\geq b$, then $a\succ b$.
$\textbf{ADD}$: $(a_1,a_2)\succeq (b_1,b_2)$ implies that $(a_1+t,a_2+s)\succeq (b_1+t,b_2+s)$ for any $(t,s)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.
$\textbf{CON}$: The upper and lower contour sets are closed.

I want to prove these axioms hold if and only if $(\succeq)$ has a linear representation, i.e., if there is $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ that represents preferences which has form $$u((x_1,x_2))=\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2$$ where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in [0,\infty)$.
Proving such a representation implies the axioms is trivial.
To prove the reverse implication, we want to take a similar approach to the proof of the vNM representation theorem and first prove that independence holds. Thence, we can conclude that a linear representation exists by Milnor and Herstein's mixture space theorem. In any case, rationality and continuity already get us a representation, so I just want to show it can be made linear.
First, I claim that $x\sim y \iff \frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}z\sim \frac{1}{2}y+\frac{1}{2}z$ for any $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^2$. My professor argues in the following way. By $\textbf{ADD}$, adding $\frac{1}{2}z$ to both sides, $$\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}z\sim \frac{1}{2}y+\frac{1}{2}z \iff \frac{1}{2}x\sim \frac{1}{2}y$$ Further, again by $\textbf{ADD}$, adding $\frac{1}{2}y$ to both sides, $$\frac{1}{2}x\sim \frac{1}{2}y\iff \frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y\sim y$$ From here, my professor claims that this shows $$\frac{1}{2}x\sim \frac{1}{2}y \iff x\sim y$$ Why does this follow?
Additionally, after showing $x\sim y \iff \frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}z\sim \frac{1}{2}y+\frac{1}{2}z$, he claims we can repeatedly apply this relation $2^n$ times, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, to obtain $$x\sim y \iff \alpha x+(1-\alpha)z\sim\alpha y+(1-\alpha)z$$ for any $\alpha=\frac{k}{2^n}$ with $0\leq k \leq 2^n$. Why is this true? How can we access $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$ by applying this relation?
After extending by $\textbf{CON}$ to any $\alpha$, he concludes that setting $z=0$ gives that $$x\sim y \iff \lambda x\sim \lambda y$$ for any $\lambda>0$. Then, by $\textbf{CON}$ and $\textbf{MON}$, $(1,0)\sim(0,k)$ for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$. Why does such a $k$ exist? For $k\leq 0$, $(1,0)\geq (0,k)$, but for $k>0$ they cannot be ordered by pointwise inequality, so how do we conclude such a $k$ exists?
In summary, my questions are,

Why is it that $x\sim y\iff \frac{1}{2}x\sim \frac{1}{2}y$?
How do we then show that $$x\sim y \iff \alpha x+(1-\alpha)z\sim\alpha y+(1-\alpha)z$$ for any $\alpha=\frac{k}{2^n}$ with $0\leq k \leq 2^n$?
Why is it true that $(1,0)\sim(0,k)$ for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$?



Concerning your first question, a simple symmetry will do (I think).
$$
\begin{align*}
&x/2  + z/2  \sim y/2  + z/2 ,\\
\to &x/2  \sim y/2, &&\text{(subtract $z/2$)}\\
\to &x/2  + y/2  \sim y \text{ and } x \sim y/2  + x/2, &&\text{(add $y/2$ and $x/2$ respectively)}\\
\to & x \sim y &&\text{(by transitivity of the above)}
\end{align*}
$$
Using a similar reasoning, we see that $x \succeq y$ is equivalent to $x/2 \succeq y/2$

For your second question, note that by repeated application of $x \sim y \to x/2 \sim y/2$ we get:
$$
x \sim y \to x/2 \sim y/2 \to \ldots \to x/2^n \sim y/2^n.
$$
Now, let us show that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \sim y \to kx/2^n \sim ky/2^n$. We proceed by induction. For $k = 1$ we have the result as $x \sim y \to x/2^n \sim y/2^n$. Assume it holds up to $k$ and consider the case $k+1$.
Then,
$$
\begin{align*}
&x \sim y \to kx/2^n \sim ky/2^n \text{ and } x/2^n \sim y/2^n,\\
\to &kx/2^n + x/2^n \sim ky/2^n + x/2^n \text{ and } ky/2^n + x/2^n \sim ky/2^n + y/2^n,&&\\
\to &(k+1)x/2^n \sim ky /2^n + x/2^n \text{ and } ky/2^n + x/2^n \sim (k+1)y/2^n\\
\to &(k+1)x/2^n \sim (k+1)y/2^n && \text{(by transitivity)}
\end{align*}
$$
Note that similarly, we can show that $x \succeq y$ implies $kx/2^n \succeq ky/2^n$. For all $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let us first show that there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(1,0) \preceq (0,2^n)$. If not, then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(1,0) \succ (0, 2^n)$.
The latter implies that (multiplying boths sides by $1/2^n$ and using steps 1 and 2 above),
$$
(1/2^n, 0) \succeq (0,1)
$$
Taking the limit for $n \to \infty$, continuity gives that,
$$
(0,0) \succeq (0,1),
$$
which contradicts monotonicity.
This shows that there is some $K \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $(1,0) \preceq (0,K)$. Now let,
$$
k = \inf \{k \in \mathbb{R}| (1,0) \preceq (0,k)\}
$$
Note that the set $\{k \in \mathbb{R}| (1,0) \preceq (0,k)\}$ is bounded from below by $0$ as $(1,0) \succ (0,0)$ by monotoncity, so this infimum is well defined. Also, by continuity, the upper contour sets are closed, so,
$(1,0) \preceq (0,k)$. Given that $k$ is the infimum, we in fact have $(1,0) \sim (0,k)$.



Thank you for your answer! You've made everything clear to me now.
